# Why is item height in Android not wrapping content?

Tags: android, xml, listview, height

I've got a `ListView` item (a single row of the list) defined in this way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:padding="6dip" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
        android:contentDescription="TODO"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/secondLine"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="26dip"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="Author"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/firstLine"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/secondLine"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="Title"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

As you can see I've got two `TextView`s and an `ImageView`. The firstLine view could be multiline. The problem is that it is not wrapping the content when I've got more than one line.

The height of a single row should change when the firstLine height changes, and the ImageView should be always centered in the row, even if its height changes. How to achieve this?

Comment: Do you have the code where you are actually inflating the row into the listview? My guess is you are not passing the container into your LayoutInflater and it therefore doesn't know how to layout the row item relative to the container.

Comment: Is the textview getting cut off because the row height is too small or is it just going continuously off the side of the screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]You can achieve your required UI very easily in a Linear Layout like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="#3d92ff" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
        android:contentDescription="TODO"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/firstLine"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@id/secondLine"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:maxHeight="60dp"
            android:text="This is multiline text , 
        I am line no 2
        I am line 3
        i am aline 4
        i am aline 5"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/secondLine"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="26dip"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="Author"
            android:textSize="12sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your list view items have fixed height = `?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight`, which make impossible to expand their height. I have modified your layout, now it should work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="6dip" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
        android:contentDescription="TODO"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/firstLine"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="Title"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/secondLine"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/firstLine"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="Author"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```